# Dynamically grouping Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

all,

I have a question on grouping Pandas columns based on name. I'm working with climate model data, and I have two indices at hand - one with unique names for each model member (for example, starting with A,B,C,etc.) and one with different simulations from within each model member (for instance, member 'A' may contain AA,AB,AC,etc.) I would like to group all of the columns starting with a particular string (for instance, I would want to group AA,AB,AC based on their beginning with A). The groups of simulations do not have equivalent lengths, so I cannot group based upon set intervals.

Any insight as to code that would solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a temporary variable with regex to match your pattern ? E.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id" : ["AB", "AC", "AA", "BC", "CD"], 
            "value" : [1,1,1,1,1]})

df.assign(grp = df["id"].str.contains(r"^A", regex=True)).groupby("grp").sum() # match all ids starting with "A"
```